# What's the equivalent of Css "display:none" in flex?

Tags: css, apache-flex

I tried this way,but not working:

```
<mx:Box includeInLayout="false" visible="false">
```

How to achieve the same as `display:none`?

Comment: How it's not working? What is wrong?

Comment: When set to visible="false" most element in the panel still occupy space in that panel and are just invisible.

Comment: So in flex I can't achieve the same as `display:none` ?

Comment: I see no reason why this would not work, this is a technique I use regularly to "remove" components without actually removing them from the display list.  Can you define "not working" and maybe post some additional code?

Comment: It's actually occupying the space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to completely hide a flex component like display:none is to set the 2 properties together

1. includeInLayout
2. visible

Only the 2 together combined, will result in display:none.

visible=false alone will result in visibility:hidden